# Weird behavior of git

Tags: git

The other day, I upgraded tiny_mce in a project that's version-controlled with git.
At that time, I made a git branch for the change and merged it to master and deleted the branch.
Everything worked fine.

Also, I changed the remote repo to another server and changed my .git/config. But I found out that I made a mistake like the following.

```
[remote "new_repo"]
  url = ssh://username@git.mydomain.com/~/path/to/myproject.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/new_repo/*
[branch "master"]
  remote = old_repo <= WRONG
  merge = refs/heads/master
```

It should be **remote = new_repo**. I corrected it later and it seemed to work fine.

But after that, if I do "git status", the old tiny_mce files overrode the new one and they are in the changed list but not committed.
So I have to "git reset --hard HEAD".
That happens on other copy of my project (updated via git), too.
But I can't reproduce it.
It seems to happen randomly.(or I just can't find the pattern yet.)

What's going on and how can I fix it?

Here's my "git branch -a":

```
choir
* master
remotes/old_repo/master
remotes/new_repo/master
```

Updates and fixes:

It turned out that tiny_mce gem that my rails application uses copies the old tiny_mce and overwrites the new one every time I run "rake some_task".
I upgraded the tiny_mce gem.

Comment: You somehow break your working directory all the time. Maybe it is due to old references (remember that git checkout branch can checkout remote branches too!). Can you describe the output of git branch -a command?

Comment: @AlexandrPriymak I edited my question to add "git branch -a". Thanks.

Comment: Did you remove local master branch lately and then just 'git checkout master'?

Comment: @AlexandrPriymak No, I haven't removed local master.

Answer (score 1):

1. The `remotes/old_repo/master` is a result of your manual rename.  In future, prefer `git remote rename`, or even just `git remote set-url` to update your remotes, and it'll clean up all these kind of things for you.

   Cleaning up after the fact is a pain; `git remote prune` is supposed to deal with these problems, but refuses to do so if the remote has gone missing.  `git branch -dr old_repo/master`?
2. `git reset --hard HEAD` will do very little if your `HEAD` is wrong.

   Inspect it with `git symbolic-ref HEAD`, or just `cat .git/HEAD`, or, even better, run `git branch -avv`.  These will tell you where your `HEAD` is pointing.

   It's probably pointing at `old_repo/master` instead of `new_repo/master`?  If so, you can (assuming you're aware of what `reset --hard` does to your uncommitted changes), `git reset --hard new_repo/master`, and never speak of this again.

Comment: Do I take either of the two or both? Anyway, "git branch -avv" is currently like this.    choir                      3a57351 override tiny_mce  
* master                     9c313f3 [ps_git/master] Remove a.txt  
  remotes/codepremise/master 974b657 Upgrade tiny_mce  
  remotes/ps_git/master      9c313f3 Remove a.txt